# Prioritising an NSButton over window resizing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, resize, nswindow, nsbutton

I have an `NSButton` in the bottom right corner of an `NSWindow`. The latter is resizeable.

If I try to click my `NSButton`, the resizing cursor
[image: resize] shows as long as my cursor is close to the corner. It's a little inconvenient, at this point I'm wondering, is there any way to prioritise the `NSButton` hover over the resizing?

Comment: I would recommend increasing the spacing towards the edge. Everything else is a hack :)

Comment: Yes so far I just tweak the UI a little, hacks would still be welcome though as an icon in the bottom right corner seems most appropriate for what I'm after.

Comment: Is the behaviour you're seeing any different to what's happening in Mail.app bottom left corner? It seems to be ok there with the plus icon and window resizing.

Comment: The behaviour is similar in the Mail app, there too I find the resizing cursor slightly obtrusive. Their plus button is further away from the corner than my button is, so it's not as bad.

Comment: I think you should be able to set a different cursor for the button using this approach: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CursorMgmt/Tasks/ChangingCursors.html

Comment: That doesn't work, the resizing cursor is still prioritised. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: Did you try using NSTrackingArea? I'm not sure if it works but you could give it a try. There's a thread with an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652158/change-mouse-cursor-over-inactive-nswindow

Comment: `-mouseEntered:` gets called just fine, the cursor does not change as I call `[self.cursor push]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83078/discussion-between-csch-and-bruno).