# Replicate cursor behaviour from the macOS screenshot tool

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, nscursor

*Disclaimer; barely a novice when it comes to Swift/macOS development.*

---

The **Ctrl+Shift+4** screenshot tool on macOS, has an accompanying cursor change that I've been looking for a way to replicate.

In its initial launch state, it's a crosshair with pixel coordinates, and switching it to window capture, by pressing space, changes the cursor to a camera.

No matter if you tab to other applications, the cursor remains changed, globally.

I've tried to replicate this behaviour by creating an see-through fullscreen **NSWindow** with a **.floating** level and changing the cursor for the content view.

This works, sort of... But has some annoying quirks.

Firstly it seems the opacity of the view cannot be a strict zero, but at least some fraction >= 0.01. I found no mention of this in the docs of **NSView**, but it's mentioned for **UIView** [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest). For the built-in screenshot tool, there doesn't seem to be any 0.01 alpha overlay.

Secondly, tabbing to any application, the **.floating** window is still on top, but makes the view loose focus, which means the cursor turns back to default. In this case, the built-in screenshot tool has a very short delay, when a new application is fronted, and then changes the cursor to the custom one again.

Am I taking the completely completely wrong approach, or do I just need to twist some nobs and dials, for this one to work?

Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to be possible. The window server can simply do things that user-land applications can't. In principle, each application controls the shape of the cursor *while that application is active*. Imagine the chaos that would ensue if any application could change the cursor for your application. So no, I don't think a user-land application can force the cursor to change globally.

Comment: I don't think this will help you—but who knows: You don't have to set the `alpha` of view/window to nearly 0.0. Just make the background of the window and the content of the view transparent (`NSColor.clearColor`). Remember to set/return `NO` from `isOpaque`.

Comment: Mareks-MacBook-Pro-2:Downloads xhruso00$ whereis screencapture
/usr/sbin/screencapture => Use Hopper (trail) to reveal code. If you can get hands on 10.10 version it is very easy to read Objective-C code dissasembly than Swift code dissasembly https://imgur.com/a/yfyFFyS

Comment: @JamesBucanek I can understand why something like that might be limited, I just haven't come across any documentation, that it's explicitly not possible. Perhaps I need to look into accessibility APIs and extended capabilities.

Comment: [This dirty hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32195746) shall help you keep the cursor shape despite your window losing focus.