# Mouse cursor change to resize cursor according to the application border BEHIND my app (my app set as TOP MOST WINDOW)

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-catalina, appkit

[image]

The screenshot remove the mouse cursor, but I'll explain the situation.
I want to understand if this is normal behaviour, cause it feel very strange.

In the screenshot I took, the app with "Posts" is my app, I set it to be **always top most window**.
When it's not **active** ( 3 round controls are gray), The cursor changes to **resize** cursor when it on the **border** of the application that **behind** my app.

What I want :
the mouse cursor will act according to my app (which is set as **always top most window**) even if not **active**.

Again. screenshot is not showing the mouse cursor, but imagine it on **my app** but over the bottom app border, and it change to **resize** cursor according to the bottom app.

If my app is **active** the mouse cursor works O.K

UPDATE : I can't reproduce the bug. I love developing. to be continue.

UPDATE 2: I can reproduce the bug. the cursor is not always changing, but the scrollbar **behind** my app is highlighting. is that normal if my app is NOT active but TOP MOST WINDOW ?

UPDATE 3: I reproduce the bug and got video that I will upload soon.

IMPORTANT UPDATE 4 :
I think I finally understand why it was so hard to reproduce this bug. it's only happen with **Opera** browser. on Safari and Chrome (acting as behind app) the mouse cursor works ok.

What so special about **Opera** browser ? :)
Can anyone test this also, so we all know I'm not crazy ?

btw - on Safari the scrollbar is also highlight if the mouse cursor is on the scrollbar track (behind the top app). on chrome the scrollbar is work as expected. (the mouse cursor on the top app not effecting the scrollbar highlight on the behind app)

UPDATE 5:
Video Link :
https://streamable.com/n3odc3

Video Description :
behind my app there is Opera browser instance that is active that load web page.
you can see the mouse cursor change to -hand- cursor because of the banner, and then to resize cursor because of the app border. also the scrollbar highlights.

What I expect is the mouse cursor will not change at all and not confuse the user. (I think this is crazy)

btw - sorry for my crappy English.

Update 6 : (reply to Willeke question if this happen with Opera and Keyboard Viewer also)
comment :
"@Willeke. I test Opera and Keyboard viewer and it also happen. I notice another thing, the 3 control buttons (red, green, yellow) in Opera are not gray if other app is active, most of the time.."

Comment: This seems like normal behavior to me. If another app is active, then the user expects to be able to manipulate its windows, even if there's another window floating above it.

Comment: how you can manipulate window size by dragging the border, if the border is behind another app  ? the only thing the user see is strange/whierd resize mouse cursor on the top (but not active app)

Comment: If you use command-option-5 to take your screen shot, the Options menu in the screen capture control bar will let you enable “Show Mouse Pointer”.

Comment: Sorry it's command-shift-5 to show the screen capture control bar.

Comment: @robmayoff thanks of the tip, but when I do it, the cursor change to arrow cursor (from resize cursor).

Comment: I see what you mean. That is frustrating.

Comment: What technology are you using in your app?

Comment: @PabloDarde all the app is built in code (except of the xib of menu) with appKit.

Comment: is it "orderFrontRegardless" that you use?

Comment: I believe this is because an inactive window, per default, doesn't interact with the mouse hover event.

Why just specifically the opera browser seems to make this work through an inactive app I'm quite unsure, but I think they've made the same kind of code for the cursor that you desire.

So, how do one **change mouse cursor over inactive window with appkit**? 

Hopefully this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21839830/9476349

Comment: Is the issue reproducable with the Keyboard Viewer?

Comment: @Willeke. I test Opera and Keyboard viewer and it also happen. I notice another thing, the 3 control buttons (red, green, yellow) in Opera are not gray if other app is active, most of the time..