# SwiftUI onHover doesn't register mouse leaving the element if mouse moves too fast

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I've made some custom slider views in SwiftUI that change appearance based on hover state, but if the mouse moves out too fast (which is actually a very reasonable speed of moving a cursor), it stays in the hover state until you re-hover and re-leave the component slowly.

Is there a solution for this?
The hover code is pretty standard:

```swift
struct RulerSlider: View {
  @State var hovering = false

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ZStack {
        // Ruler lines
        if hovering {
          Ruler()
        }
      }
      .onHover { hover in
        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.1)) {
          self.hovering = hover
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what the issue looks like:

[image]

Sample code for reproducing the bug:
https://gist.github.com/rdev/ea0c53448e12835b29faa11fec8e0388

Comment: Try w/o animation, try to make rows (in parent view) unique. If not helpful please prepare standalone minimal reproducible example for debugging.

Comment: I tried doing it without animation, same result. It looks like the 'mouseleave' event (or whatever is the swift equivalent of it) is not being fired if the mouse doesn't move out of the view slow enough

Comment: Added a gist link with reproducible code. It doesn't happen as much in a stripped down example though, but still happens.

Comment: I also see this in my apps. Even with a background that tries to nil out on mouse exit.

Comment: This is still an issue (2023-05-11) an you need a mouse-tracking view that fires these events more reliably

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I resolved this issue today with a tracking area on an empty NSView. This is tested in a semi-complex and quickly refreshing grid view, which previously had the same behavior you pictured. About 75 views have this modifier applied in the [GIF capture in this gist](https://gist.github.com/importRyan/c668904b0c5442b80b6f38a980595031), most with zero border to each other.

#### Sugar for call site

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func whenHovered(_ mouseIsInside: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(MouseInsideModifier(mouseIsInside))
    }
}
```

#### Representable with empty tracking view

```swift
struct MouseInsideModifier: ViewModifier {
    let mouseIsInside: (Bool) -> Void
    
    init(_ mouseIsInside: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        self.mouseIsInside = mouseIsInside
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Representable(mouseIsInside: mouseIsInside,
                              frame: proxy.frame(in: .global))
            }
        )
    }
    
    private struct Representable: NSViewRepresentable {
        let mouseIsInside: (Bool) -> Void
        let frame: NSRect
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            let coordinator = Coordinator()
            coordinator.mouseIsInside = mouseIsInside
            return coordinator
        }
        
        class Coordinator: NSResponder {
            var mouseIsInside: ((Bool) -> Void)?
            
            override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
                mouseIsInside?(true)
            }
            
            override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
                mouseIsInside?(false)
            }
        }
        
        func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
            let view = NSView(frame: frame)
            
            let options: NSTrackingArea.Options = [
                .mouseEnteredAndExited,
                .inVisibleRect,
                .activeInKeyWindow
            ]
            
            let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: frame,
                                              options: options,
                                              owner: context.coordinator,
                                              userInfo: nil)
            
            view.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
            
            return view
        }
        
        func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
        
        static func dismantleNSView(_ nsView: NSView, coordinator: Coordinator) {
            nsView.trackingAreas.forEach { nsView.removeTrackingArea($0) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ryan - is it even possible you can be this smart ! :-) Thanks so much.  Why is it Apples on onHover() modified does just use this ??

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Haha I dunno if I am... but if so, hire me as a jr dev!

Comment: @Ryan - actually there is an issue with this as it prevents other gestures from occurring for example .onTapGesture() has to outside the .whenHovered() modifier. So you need to put it underneath any controls that need to respond to gesture events it seems. For example HStack { Toggle($isOn, label:{...} }..overlay(...).whenHovered {..} means Toggle() will not get any mouse events.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Can you open a new question with code? I don't observe interference when .whenHovered is applied outside Toggle in my own project, or with a gesture applied to the Toggle label. Without .whenHovered, applying a tap gesture outside a Toggle doesn't work.

Comment: Great! Works perfectly

Comment: So many problems would be solved with an open source swiftui... Thanks for the wrapper!

Comment: FYI: This appears fixed in Monterey.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this super easily without leaving SwiftUI environment (unlike accepted answer) by actually applying `onHover` in a container view to your `RulerSliders`. In other words, keep track of which element is currently hovered (if any) in `List`, instead of list children.

```
public struct RulersList {
    @State private var hoveredRulerId: RulerModel.ID? = nil
    public let rulers: [RulerModel]
    public var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(rulers) { ruler in
                RulerSlider(ruler, ruler.id == hoveredRulerId)
                    .onHover(perform: { isHovering in
                        self.hoveredRulerId = isHovering ? ruler.id : nil
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct RulerSlider: View {
    public let ruler: RulerModel
    public var isHovered
    public var body: some View {
        Stuff()
            .background(isHovered ? Color.accentColor.opacity(0.10) : Color.clear)
            // DON'T DO onHover HERE, IT HAS SEVERE PERFORMANCE PENALTY
    }
}
```

Do note `RulerSlider(ruler, ruler.id == hoveredRulerId)` inside the `ForEach`, this is how you inform child view whether it's being hovered or not.

Comment: Very interesting! Neat. Do you know why this is the case? Good to know there's this option, although it's too bad the native way requires a parent to know and manage details of the child.

Comment: My guess would be performance? If you apply `onHover` modifier for every child view in list, then tracking cursor focus and updating binding value has to be calculated for each subview separately, each needing separate atomic transaction. However if you setup the container itself as the tracking element, then you just check if cursor's CGPoint is inside frame of any child views and then update all dependent Bindings in the same Transaction. But I don't have access to the SwiftUI source, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: Makes sense. Using hundreds of AppKit NSResponders is more responsive than the child-modifier and doesn't turn out to be expensive. Something's odd with the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

`onHover` is laggy if you apply it per individual child view. It works as expected though if you apply it in parent container view. Here is an example:

```
struct ContainerView: View {
    var elements = (0..<10).map { "\($0)" }
    
    @State private var lastHoveredId = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
                ChildView(lastHoveredId: $lastHoveredId, id: element)
                    .onHover { isHovered in
                        if isHovered {
                            lastHoveredId = element
                        } else if lastHoveredId == element {
                            lastHoveredId = ""
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var lastHoveredId: String
    var id: String
    
    @State private var isHovered = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(id)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 30)
            .background(isHovered ? Color.primary.opacity(0.2) : .clear)
            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.2))
            .onChange(of: lastHoveredId) {
                isHovered = $0 == id
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

macOS 14.0, Xcode 15.0 - can't reproduce this bug