# How can I read and get access to mouse cursor location in a view of macOS SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my very simple and starter project, as you can see in question title I want to read the mouse cursor location when it hover or move on my view in macOS SwiftUI.
For starter project I used gesture! The issue with gesture is there that the user should do some kind of tap or drag and that would trigger the gesture, but I want to get all benefit of gesture without having to make a tap or drag, how can I do this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var location: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {

        return VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("location is: ( \(location.x), \(location.y))").bold()
                Spacer()
            }

            Spacer()
 
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                    .onEnded { value in location = value.location })

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This might help: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678661?answerId=671933022#671933022

Comment: Also: https://swiftui-lab.com/a-powerful-combo/

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66430835/12299030?

Answer (score 5):

try using the code below, note that it will provide the current overall mouse position inside the screen, not only inside the window.
However you can use the method **.onHover**  in order to know when the mouse is over a view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var mouseLocation: NSPoint { NSEvent.mouseLocation }
@State var isOverContentView: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        //Place your view
        Image(systemName: "applelogo")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .onHover{ on in
                isOverContentView = on
            }
    }
    .frame(width: 600, height: 600)
    .onAppear(perform: {
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) {
            print("\(isOverContentView ? "Mouse inside ContentView" : "Not inside Content View") x: \(self.mouseLocation.x) y: \(self.mouseLocation.y)")
            return $0
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: this answer is just a copy of what @aheze already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: How can I get the location relevant to my View? That is what I am looking for! It is better than nothing to read the screen location, but it is not useful for me, I need the location based on my view.